Generate a slots board from result
i have made this code that generates a combination of 3-5 of different symbols to result in a random float. And now i'm trying to make it into a board, where it shows up as paylines like the real slot machines, but i can't figure out how to do it without it giving exceptions or looking really weird.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static test.Program;

namespace test
{
    internal class Program
    {
        // Define a structure to represent a line and its payout
        public struct Line
        {
            public string Symbol;
            public int Length;
            public float Payout;

            public Line(string symbol, int length, float payout)
            {
                Symbol = symbol;
                Length = length;
                Payout = payout;
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return $"{Symbol} {Length}x {Payout}";
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                // Define the paytable
                List<Line> paytable = new List<Line>
                {
                    new Line("J", 3, 0.1f),
                    new Line("J", 4, 0.3f),
                    new Line("J", 5, 0.6f),
                    new Line("Q", 3, 0.7f),
                    new Line("Q", 4, 1.5f),
                    new Line("Q", 5, 3.0f),
                    new Line("K", 3, 1.5f),
                    new Line("K", 4, 5.0f),
                    new Line("K", 5, 10.0f),
                    new Line("A", 3, 3.0f),
                    new Line("A", 4, 10.0f),
                    new Line("A", 5, 20.0f),
                };

                paytable.Reverse();

                float maxWin = 280;

                float target = GetRandomFloat(maxWin);

                // List to hold the result
                List<Line> result = new List<Line>();

                // Find the combination
                bool success = FindCombination(paytable, target, new List<Line>(), result);

                if (success)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Combination found for {target}:");

                    foreach (var line in result)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                    } 
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"No combination found for {target}.");
                }

                Console.ReadKey(true);
            }
        }


        static float GetRandomFloat(float max)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int scale = (int)(max * 10); // Scale to work with integers
            int randomValue = random.Next(0, scale + 1);
            return randomValue / 10f; // Convert back to float with 1 decimal
        }

        static bool FindCombination(List<Line> paytable, float target, List<Line> current, List<Line> result)
        {
            // Base case: if target is close enough to zero
            if (Math.Abs(target) < 0.1f)
            {
                result.AddRange(current);
                return true;
            }

            // Base case: if more than 20 lines are used
            if (current.Count >= 20)
            {
                return false;
            }

            // Explore each line in the paytable
            foreach (var line in paytable)
            {
                if (line.Payout <= target)
                {
                    current.Add(line);
                    if (FindCombination(paytable, target - line.Payout, current, result))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    current.RemoveAt(current.Count - 1);
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}


Maybe add an example for an output. I have no idea what you are aiming for without.

You don't need float values for the payout values (or money values in general, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency), use int values instead (and change the amount to "cents" instead of "dollars" or what the currency is you are using).

You can change the fore- and background colors of the console output to improve the visual impact.
